# In R, Filling value of multiple cells from the value of other multiple cells in other rows based on repeated ID?

Tags: r, filter, filtering, na

This might be a little confusing, however, please look at the table below:

```
ID  |  PatientID  |  VisitCode  |  EXAMDATE  |  AGE
--------------------------------------------------------
1   |  7362       |  BL      | 21/08/2015 |     19
2   |  7362       |  M06     | 21/08/2015 |     NA
3   |  7362       |  M36     | 21/08/2015 |     NA

4   |  7363       |  BL      | 21/08/2015 |     NA
5   |  7363       |  M36     | 21/08/2015 |     70

6   |  7366       |  BL      | 21/08/2015 |     NA
7   |  7366       |  M03     | 21/08/2015 |     65
8   |  7366       |  M06     | 21/08/2015 |     NA
9   |  7366       |  M012    | 21/08/2015 |     NA
```

The example above shows data for 3 patient recorded at different visits. The problem is that in some of the visits some of the data was filled in as **NA** because it was not available of because it was already recorded in previous visits.

Expected output:

```
ID  |  PatientID  |  VisitCode  |  EXAMDATE  |  AGE
--------------------------------------------------------
1   |  7362       |  BL      | 21/08/2015 |     19
2   |  7362       |  M06     | 21/08/2015 |     19
3   |  7362       |  M36     | 21/08/2015 |     19

4   |  7363       |  BL      | 21/08/2015 |     70
5   |  7363       |  M36     | 21/08/2015 |     70

6   |  7366       |  BL      | 21/08/2015 |     65
7   |  7366       |  M03     | 21/08/2015 |     65
8   |  7366       |  M06     | 21/08/2015 |     65
9   |  7366       |  M012    | 21/08/2015 |     65
```

I want to have a code that replaces the NA's for each patient based on the most recent visits where it is not NA.
Visits code list:

- BL
- M03
- M06
- M012
- M036

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the expected output data. Also be sure that your example isn't too simplified. If there are cases with two values for the same ID, you should add the desired behavior. Make the example as varied as the cases you may run into.

Comment: You said 3 patients, but I can see 2 unique IDs....

Comment: @PierreLafortune sorry about the confusion I have added the expected output

Comment: @AntoniosK it was a typing error I have changed the IDs thank you

Comment: @jeremycg 's solution is great for what you asked. But as @PierreLafortune mentioned you should think if the sample you provided is oversimplified. Eg. If patient `7362` visited last year when he was 18 then by grouping only on `PatientID` will replace everything (NAs and 19) with 18. So, with a simplified example you will get a great answer but you'll have to do lots of debugging for your real dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(PatientID) %>%
        mutate(AGE = AGE[!is.na(AGE)][1])

Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
Groups: PatientID [3]

     ID PatientID VisitCode   EXAMDATE   AGE
  (int)     (int)    (fctr)     (fctr) (int)
1     1      7362        BL 21/08/2015    19
2     2      7362       M06 21/08/2015    19
3     3      7362       M36 21/08/2015    19
4     4      7363        BL 21/08/2015    70
5     5      7363       M36 21/08/2015    70
6     6      7366        BL 21/08/2015    65
7     7      7366       M03 21/08/2015    65
8     8      7366       M06 21/08/2015    65
9     9      7366      M012 21/08/2015    65
```